# How to show Progress Bar in one Window while another is Opening

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, window, progress-bar

I have a very basic problem, which alas, I haven't been able to resolve I have a Window called `Login`, which has well, Login logic. When the user authenticates himself, I'm opening the Main Window which in my case is `Test` (The naming is bad, I know). The `Test` window, is a fairly big window (In terms of UI and Data), and houses a multitude of User Controls which themselves load `Datagrids`. Hence as a result, after pressing the login button, the app's UI freezes for some time and then the `Test` window appears. I would want to display a progress bar in `Login` and want the UI to stay responsive also. How should I achieve this.

Comment: All UI tasks run on the main thread, if a form load keeps busy the thread you can't do any UI related task meanwhile.

Comment: I am ready to use another Thread to open the other window. Can I do this then?

Comment: No, it will crash, you can't interact with the UI from a secondary thread.

Comment: I want to get rid of the app freezing, what would you advise me do? Also if I can show some progress that would be great.

Comment: The only way to avoid "freezing" the UI is to do the long-running work in some other thread. See marked duplicate. Note that the UI itself does need to be constructed in the UI thread. You need to construct all the underlying _data_ in the background thread, so it can be bound to the UI in the UI thread. How best to do that depends on the specific details; if you have trouble, post a new question in which you provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and a clear explanation of what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.